# Could not find com.android.tools:r8:1.5.25

Tags: java, android, flutter

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download r8-1.6.84.jar (com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/r8/1.6.84/r8-1.6.84.jar'.
> > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4,257,995; received: 2,097,136)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84'
      //  classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.4.57'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')

    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Full Error message here :

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download r8-1.6.84.jar (com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/r8/1.6.84/r8-1.6.84.jar'.
> > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 4,257,995; received: 2,097,136)
> Could not download bundletool-0.13.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.13.2)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.13.2/bundletool-0.13.2.jar'.
> > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 32,326,603; received: 2,359,280)
> Could not download builder-4.0.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.0.0)
> > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.0.0/builder-4.0.0.jar'.
> > Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 9,052,896; received: 4,456,416)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13m 48s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Are you sure that version 1.5.25 exists? It doesn't seem to be listed in the googleapis repo you're using in gradle.

Comment: Even I have changed the version to 1.6.84. Same similar error is showinng.

Comment: Have you tried pulling your artifacts from google's maven repo (maven.google.com) instead of the googleapi site?

Comment: What is the reason for trying using R8 `1.6.84` with AGP 4.0.0? AGP 4.0.0 is bundled with the newer R8 `2.0.74`, and using an older version is not recommended. Unless you are having an explicit issue with R8 you should stick to the one bundled with AGP, so just remove the line `classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.6.84'` to avoid staying on an old compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`? This usually solves common build errors. If that didn't solve the issue, you can rebuild the Flutter project's `/android` folder by deleting it and running `flutter create --platform=android [PROJECT_PATH]` to generate the Android project again.